# How to automatically put JS files into a AJAX-called page?

Tags: javascript, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, file

Into my app I have included all needed JS files (my scripts, libraries such as Twitter Bootstrap etc.).

The problem is, that when I have a request which is called via AJAX, so in the called page are not included the JS files, which are included in my app and I have to include them into the called page.

Example: **my_scripts.js** contains lots of JS functions.

link to page called through AJAX

```
<a href="/articles/create_new" data-remote="true>Create New Article</a>
```

**/views/articles/_create_new.html.haml**

```
...some content of this file.. #here doesn't work the functions from the file "my_scripts.js"
```

when I put into the **/views/articles/_create_new.html.haml** this link

```
= javascript_include_tag "my_scripts"
...some content of this file..
```

so then in the **/views/articles/_create_new.html.haml** those JS functions working.

I would like to ask you, if exist any way, how to automatically put all JS files in my every single AJAX pages, because always include the JS files into an AJAX pages is not good way...

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a script loader like [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/) or [$cript](http://dustindiaz.com/scriptjs).

Have your pages reply 2 things also: the content and the scripts to load. This is best using JSON like:

```
{
    "content" : "content here",
    "scripts" : ["an","array","of","script","urls"]
}
```

then when the data is returned, parse and paint the content and after that, use the script loaders to load the scripts. Actually, you can make your own script loader. It's just a matter of dynamically creating a `<script>` tag, put it in the `<head>` and give it an `src`

Answer (score 1):

I would achieve this in one of three ways:

**jQuery**

From http://api.jquery.com/load/:

> Script Execution When calling .load() using a URL without a suffixed
>   selector expression, the content is passed to .html() prior to scripts
>   being removed. This executes the script blocks before they are
>   discarded. If .load() is called with a selector expression appended to
>   the URL, however, the scripts are stripped out prior to the DOM being
>   updated, and thus are not executed. An example of both cases can be
>   seen below:
>
> Here, any JavaScript loaded into #a as a part of the document will
>   successfully execute.
>
> `$('#a').load('article.html');`
>
> However, in the following case, script
>   blocks in the document being loaded into #b are stripped out and not
>   executed:
>
> `$('#b').load('article.html #target');`

Basically, you can add the JS references to the HTML returned by Ajax request and jQuery will execute them.

**RequireJS or simular**

Rather than return straight HTML, return the HTML as part of a JSON bundle that also contains an array of script references:

```
{
    html: '<p>stuff</p>',
    scriptRefs: [ 'js/one.js', 'js/two.js' ]
}
```

I would then iterate through the scriptRefs array with something like RequireJS.

**Just add the code to base page**

In all honesty, I'm more likely to just do this.